# passing date from jsp to servlet using getParameterValues

Tags: java, jsp, date, datetime, servlets

I am having error in servlet to pass the value from JSP..

JSP codes :

```
<table>                 
<tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Start</td>
    <td>End</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>                                                          
</tr>               
<tr>
   <td><select name="availableDay">  
       <!--Listing days-->                                                                                         
       </select></td>
   <td><input type="time"   name="availableStart"/></td>
   <td><input type="time"   name="availableEnd"/></td>
   <td><input type="date"   name="availableDate" /></td>
   <td><input type="button" class="add" name="action" value="Add More"</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to pass `availableDate` to servlet. Fyi, the row in JSP is dynamically generated. Thus, I pass using `[]`. My servlet codes :

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

  String[] presentationID = request.getParameterValues("selectavailability");
  String[] availableDay =  request.getParameterValues("availableDay"); 
  String[] availableStart =  request.getParameterValues("availableStart");
  String[] availableEnd =  request.getParameterValues("availableEnd");
  String[] availableDate = request.getParameterValues("availableDate");  

  SimpleDateFormat availDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Date chosenDate = availDate.parse(availableDate);// THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING ERROR

  try {

        if(availableDay != null && availableStart != null && availableEnd != null)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < availableDay.length; i++) 
          {

            AvailabilityBean available = new  AvailabilityBean(); 
            available.setLecturerID(request.getParameter("lecturerID"));
            available.setAvailableDay(availableDay[i]);
            available.setAvailableStart(availableStart[i]);
            available.setAvailableEnd(availableEnd[i]);
            available.setAvailableDate(availableDate[i]); //EFFECTED THIS LINE TOO

            available = AddAvailableDAO.addavailable(available);


           }
        }

     }
                   response.sendRedirect("addAvailability.jsp");                
 }
catch (Throwable theException) {
            System.out.println("hhhhhhh"+theException);
        }
    }
```

For extra, AvailabilityBean:

```
    private String availableID;
    private String lecturerID;
    private String availableDay;
    private String availableStart;
    private String availableEnd;
    private Date availableDate;
    private String presentationID;
```

Error : `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String.`

Can you show me where is my mistake? And how can i solve this? Thank you

Comment: The argument type of method `java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(String source)` is String. But the type of variable `availableDate` is `String[]`. That's the point. A solution is moving the call into for loop.

Comment: Should I do it like this : Date chosenDate = availDate.parse(availableDate[i]); (inside the loop)

Comment: The variable `chosenDate` is not used now. So it depend on the purpose of that variable.

Comment: It's working :) I use the `chosenDate` like this : `Date chosenDate = availDate.parse(availableDate[i]);
                          available.setAvailableDate(chosenDate);` Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your `availableDate` Variable which is an array of `String`.

```
 String[] availableDate = request.getParameterValues("availableDate");
```

Now , you are using `SimpleDateFormat` Class to format your `String` data into `Date`.

Here `parse(String text)` will take a `String` Argument not a type of `String[]` (Array).

```
 SimpleDateFormat availDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Date chosenDate = availDate.parse(availableDate);// availableDate is a String Array not a String.
```

So, It will raise an `compile-time` error `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String.`

better you should try this

```
 Date chosenDate = availDate.parse(availableDate[0]); //preferred index you may pass as per your requirement.
```

> **Note**:- `availableDate[0]` will return a `String` Object available at index `0`.

Comment: But I have little problem. The date i retrieved is today's date, not the one selected by user....

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your JSP Code sample..

```
<td><select name="availableDay">  //only one value will get selected so. use getParameterValue() for this field too.
       <!--Listing days-->                                                                                         
       </select></td>

   //this will return only a String not a String[] . So use getParameterValue();
   <td><input type="time"   name="availableStart"/></td> 

    //this will also return only a String not a String[] . So use getParameterValue();
   <td><input type="time"   name="availableEnd"/></td> 

    //this too will return only a String not a String[] . So use getParameterValue();
   <td><input type="date"   name="availableDate" /></td> //this too will return a String with getParameterValue();
```

So, try this .. Code.

```
  String availableDay =  request.getParameter("availableDay"); 
  String availableStart =  request.getParameter("availableStart");
  String availableEnd =  request.getParameter("availableEnd");
  String availableDate = request.getParameter("availableDate");
```

instead of this one.

```
 String[] availableDay =  request.getParameterValues("availableDay"); 
  String[] availableStart =  request.getParameterValues("availableStart");
  String[] availableEnd =  request.getParameterValues("availableEnd");
  String[] availableDate = request.getParameterValues("availableDate");
```

Comment: The row is dynamically generated. So does this code able to retrieve values from the dynamic rows?

Comment: final page which will be given to the browser will be a `html` not `jsp`. So, dynamic rows is generated at server end not at client end. So, whenever you submit your application. Your <html> control should be present in `<form> tag.

Comment: Browser reads only `html` not `jsp`. for more info you can learn the concept of `life cycle of jsp` Pages.

Comment: What is the differences between `getParameterValues` and `getParameterValue`

Comment: please read this.. you will get your answer. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: @Elly Please don't feel embrace but you should read servlet First. then you should try something. HowEver I have edited my answer. its `getParameter()` not getParameterValue()` actually.

Comment: I have actually try this. Last time i used` getParameter()`, I couldnt retrieve the data from dynamic rows.